# What is the etymology of britannica?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

What is the etymology of britannica, the name of a website?

Was it formed by britan + -nica? What does -nica mean?

Comment: It's not English, it's Latin. See the [entry in wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/britannica#Latin). It means "British" in Latin.  The ending isn't a word, it's the nominative singular feminine inflection.  The masucline form is britannicus.

Comment: Like the tag says, questions about etymology are better asked in [english.SE] than here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Questions about Latin etymology belong on Latin SE, not English Language and Usage SE. [Wiktionary has an entry on Latin -icus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-icus#Latin) and [-ica](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ica#Latin)

Answer (score 3):

The website you refer to is that of **Encyclopedia Britannica**, which describes itself as 'the oldest English-language general encyclopedia', first published in 1768. The title is Latin for 'British Encyclopedia'.

Comment: Is it an encylopedia in or about English language?

Comment: It's a **general encyclopedia** (about all topics) **in** the English language.